# Presale tokens / Mist / password denied

Tags: mist, presale

My question pertains to my mist wallet and some presale tokens that I successfully imported into the wallet. Before importing the presale tokens, I successfully created the wallet, received and sent tokens from the main account.  My password and the software worked.

Then I imported the presale tokens and they ended up in an account called account 2.  I did not create the account, they just seemed to end up there as I remember... I've tried to send a token from that account but it asks for a password.  The only password I have is for the main account that was created when the wallet was first run from the downloaded from the Ethereum...cosx 0-7-3 download file.

Can you please help me figure out what is going on and gain access to my funds.

Comment: Have you tried using your presale password for account 2?

Comment: YAY! Bokky! You're my man!!!

Comment: Great! I've added an answer that is a duplicate of my comment. Can you tick it off so others that encounter your exact situation will know that this is the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using your presale password for account 2?